# How to refresh listview using Pull to refresh library

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

i using listview in my android app..
Code for listview

```
<eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/twitter_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_vector"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This listview contains tweets from different ids..

[image]

I am using pull to refresh library for refreshing list
Here is code for that

```
 list.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) list.getAdapter();
            ((StreamListAdapter)((HeaderViewListAdapter)list.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.onRefreshComplete();

        }
    });
```

But after using that nothing happens...
My list unable to refresh content..
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to refresh the adapter and list view
listView.refreshDrawableState();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: can you post the whole code, so that we can help you better